# Is it possible to merge multiple objects with getters without invoking the getters

Tags: javascript

So I have some classes in which I'd like to extend. Except these classes have getters and any time I want to merge/extend their properties by destructuring, it invokes the getter function (calls the getter functions).

Is there anyway to merge objects with getters without having the getters called?

#### Note:

> The actual problem I have involves cypress and chaining. I have deeply nested getters (in which I'd like extended classes to extend them) and it's causing unwanted side effects, like an extra chain which causes undesired behaviour.

If you run the example below, you will see multiple console.logs being called (which means multiple of the

```js
class Test {
    get obj () {
        return {
            get test () {
                const _this = this;
                return {
                    get first () {
                        const out = _this.wrapper + 'first';
                        console.log( out );
                        return out;
                    }
                };
            },
            get wrapper () {
                const out = 'wrapper';
                console.log( out );
                return out;
            }
        };
    }
}

class Test1 extends Test {
    get obj () {
        const parent = super.obj;
        return {
            ...parent,
                get test() {
                console.log( parent );
                return {
                    ...parent.test,
                    get second () {
                        return super.wrapper + 'hello';
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    }
}

const t = new Test();
const t1 = new Test1();
console.log( t1.obj.test.second );
```

Comment: So you want the "value" to be assigned to your new object? There is no way to get that value without calling "a" getter (not necessarily the one of the original object).

Comment: I'd recommend disabling the Stack Snippet console, because it'll invoke the getters while logging the object, which is very confusing. Look at the browser console instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors` to get a reference to an object's descriptors, including getters, without invoking them. Put it into a new object with `Object.defineProperties`.

To add the additional getter, use `Object.defineProperty` on the cloned object.

```js
const cloneObj = obj => Object.defineProperties({}, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj));

class Test {
  get obj() {
    return {
      get name() {
        const _this = this
        return {
          get first() {
            const out = _this.wrapper + 'first'
            console.log('get first:', out)
            return out
          }
        }
      },
      get wrapper() {
        const out = 'wrapper'
        console.log('get wrapper:', out)
        return out
      }
    }
  }
}

class Test1 extends Test {
  get obj() {
    const parent = super.obj
    const parentClone = cloneObj(parent);
    Object.defineProperty(parentClone, 'name', { get() {
      console.log('child name getter:', parent)
      const parentNameClone = cloneObj(parent.name);
      Object.defineProperty(parentNameClone, 'second', { get() {
        console.log('child second getter:', parent)
        return super.wrapper + 'hello';
      }});
      return parentNameClone;
    }});
    return parentClone;
  }
}

const t1 = new Test1()
console.log('objects fully instantiated.');
console.log(t1.obj.name.second)
```

Result:

[image]

Don't enable the Stack Snippet console, it'll be confusing because it'll invoke the getters itself while trying to display the object.

Comment: it still seems to call a lot of console.log. Which means it's invoking the getters right?

Comment: At the very end after the object is instantiated, yes, but not before - which is what you want, right? To invoke the getters when you do `console.log(t1.obj.name.second)`?

Comment: I just realized that the keyword `name` is actually reserved or has meaning inside an object. I've changed my code slightly so it doesn't clash. But I'll give your answer a try. My actual problem involves cypress, and I'm using deeply nested objects to select elements, and there's a bug involving unwanted chaining. I think I'll add this to the question as well.

Comment: OP's code also only calls the getters at the very end.. this example isn't very concluding... Maybe a simpler case would make it more clear. Maybe something like https://jsfiddle.net/z3esyqf1/

Comment: `name` is only reserved when it's a standalone identifier at the top level. It shouldn't be an issue here

Comment: And it should probably be noted that the getter may not return the correct value now, (e.g if they used `this`).

Comment: I will need to experiment a bit with this because I'm getting other issues in my code. Will mark as answer once I've tested it out

Comment: I see that you're nesting a definition for `second` inside name. Can you not just create a nested object? Is `defineProperties` also not better if I have multiple?

Comment: @A.L You want to retrieve and copy the parent getters without invoking them, so you can't use an object literal like you are with `return { ...parent.test, get second() {` - have to use some variation of `Object.defineProperty` instead. If you want to assign multiple values onto the copy, sure, use `Object.defineProperties`

Comment: From what I can observe, it still seems to still fire a lot of the getters. But the code has fixed one of the issues where it's using a wrongly chained variable due to a getter invocation.

Comment: @A.L Make sure to turn off the Stack Snippet console. Your browser console will log `objects fully instantiated`, `child name getter`, `child second getter`, then `undefined hello`. The getters only get invoked when accessed at the very end, when `console.log(t1.obj.name.second)` is done.

Comment: I mean I've used it in my code with Cypress, but I can see multiple elements being targeted. I might need to make a new question regarding that if it's specific to Cypress or something. But I think this works, as far as not invoking getters go.